# File management in Windows Store app using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, file-management

I'm developing a Windows Store app for Windows 8 surface with HTML/JavaCript using Visual Studio. I'm new to WinRT.

I have an /images folder next to my default.html when I created the template. How do I:

1. Open an image file from another directory(such as USB drive) and copy it to my images folder?
2. Create a sub-folder inside the images folder?
3. Delete any file/folder in the images folder?

Answer (score 0):

Any folder that's in your app project, and thus in your app package, is by design read-only. You use such folders for resources that are downloaded with the app to a client device, and you can get to those folders either with ms-appx:/// URIs (see [URI Schemes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj655406.aspx)) or with [Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.current.installedLocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.package.installedlocation.aspx). The latter gives you a StorageFolder object through which you can navigate to and access in-package resources.

For read-write locations, use Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.localFolder, roamingFolder, or temporaryFolder (see the [ApplicationData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.aspx) topic). Each of these is a [StorageFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.aspx) with which again you can do all the necessary file operations.

For details on copying files and so forth, I suggest you look at the following sections in my free ebook, *[Programming Windows Store Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, 2nd Edition](http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2)*, as there's too much to cover here succintly:

- Chapter 1, page 103, section "Moving the Captured Image to AppData
  (or the Pictures Library"), which covers basics
- Chapter 10, page 527, which talks all about the AppData folders and
  APIs (to page 537) and file I/O (from 537-551)